# Cast to ObjectId failed when trying to fetch data from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Hi i am new to mongodb and i have this error coming when i am hitting this endpoint `localhost:3000/api/v1/tours/1`

Error message

```
{
    "status": "failure",
    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"1\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"Tour\""
}
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNROi.png)

```
exports.getTour = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const tour = await Tour.findById(req.params.id);
    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      data: {
        tour
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({
      status: 'failure',
      message: err.message
    });
  }
};
```

this is the function which is supposed to give me the tour data with the specific id.

i am attaching the  schema here

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const tourSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'A tour must have a name'],
    unique: true
  },
  rating: {
    type: Number,
    default: 4.5
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'A tour must have a price']
  }
});

const Tour = mongoose.model('Tour', tourSchema);
```

Here is the data present in atlas database
[mongoose data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl0UK.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi i have pasted the error message in text also.Thanku

Answer (score 0):

When you issue a `GET` request to:

```
localhost:3000/api/v1/tours/1
```

Your code is grabbing `req.params.id` which is `1`. Since you are using that as a parameter to `findById()` mongoose is trying to cast `1` to an `ObjectId` for you so that it can find the document. Well firstly, `1` isn't castable to an `ObjectId` and secondly, you don't have a document with an `_id === 1`.

I think the route you need to request is:

```
localhost:3000/api/v1/tours/65756e8badeb705e687e7aa9
```

Comment: localhost:3000/api/v1/tours/65756e8badeb705e687e7aa9 it is working fine but i need to get the tour data using localhost:3000/api/v1/tours/1 as i am following the udemy course from jonas scheddman so i need to make the code same

Comment: @ArvinderKatoch Is it the `Node.js, Express, MongoDB & More: The Complete Bootcamp 2024
` ? course. That's what i get my team to use. Which section and video are you following?

Comment: yes this is the one ,I am on Section 8 (Video 90 - Reading documents). Stuck on this part

Comment: Keep watching the video. He talks about using "real" ids. What he's referring to is `ObjectId`.

Comment: so like this will not be used later on ? can i skip this part

Comment: You can skip. The `_id` is almost universally implemented as an `ObjectId`. The route `localhost:3000/api/v1/tours/1` will only work if the `_id` field is a string or number which isn't very common. That is an excellent course. Stick with it and good luck.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help and yep jonas is best

Answer (score 0):

I can see that from [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl0UK.png) image that `65756e8badeb705e68Te7aa9` this is your data ID for created Tour data.

MongoDb use `uuid` to create 12-byte random id So you have to pass `65756e8badeb705e68Te7aa9` as id to get data from mongoDb collection.

Comment: You are correct but the `ObjectId` isn't random. It's a [very specific](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) 12-byte value made up of 3 parts.

Comment: Hi i am following jonas scheddman udemy course and in that he is using localhost:3000/api/v1/tours/1 and he is able to get the tours data with specific id using this code